# How to implement drag the right corner of the QTableWidget’s items to replication the contents, as in Excel?

Tags: c++, qt, replication, qtablewidget

I am a C++ developer, I use `QTableWidget` to show my information, but now I want to implement drag the right corner of `QTableWidget`'s items to replication the contents as Excel.

What should I do ? Can somebody give me some examples of codes ?

Thank you first !

Comment: Do you want an expandable/collapsable (with or without animation) `QTableWidget` ? Is this your question ?

Comment: Do you use Excel ? If you move the mouse on the right corner of items,then drag the items and you will copy the contents to other items , I will implement use QTableWidget.

Comment: No I don't use Excel, that's why I asked :)